# Redirect editform.aspx to custom view instead of the default?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm another unfortunate admin who has been handed some developer tasks and I am struggling with what is probably a simple process that requires your help.

I have a sharepoint list called "tickets".  On this list I have created multiple filtered/grouped views of the items in the list for separate groups of users (these views are linked to from their respective sharepoint sites elsewhere in the collection).

My problem is that when a user edits one of these list items using the editform and SAVES the user is taken back to the default list view instead of the custom view I created for each group of users.

I strongly suspect I can do something like this:

"http://web.com/lists/listname/editform.aspx?Source=http://web.com/list/listname/viewname.aspx"

...but I cant figure out where to go in sharepoint (2010 server) or sharepoint designer to add the re-direct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you providing links to the views from different sites?

Comment: They're actually a subsite (with different permissions) within the same site collection but yes.  On their respective team sites the user clicks a navigation link which opens another window to a filtered view of the ticket list (which resides at the top level of the site collection).

Answer (score 1):

The redirect always takes the user back from where they started. If you change the default view to be another view then your user will be redirected automatically to this view.

Another thing you need to make sure is that the modal dialog is disabled because when the  modal dialog is closed the view in the background will be refreshed.

Comment: Then I have something configured improperly and I don't know what.  In my case if a user saves an edit to a list item SharePoint takes them back to the allitems view (which is default for the list but not where the user started).  I'll check out the modal dialog thing though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Data view webpart** with the data source as "tickets" list (and provide filter as per requirements), instead of using the view directly. You can add title field (or the required field) as hyperlink which redirects to the edit form . This url should be in the following format :
"http://web.com/lists/listname/editform.aspx?Source=http://web.com/list/listname/viewname.aspx"

You can look [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/data-view-web-part-the-basics-add-a-hyperlink.aspx.) on how to add title field as hyperlink.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have finally figured out where to add this reformatted url but the problem I have is that the link refers to a specific item in order to open the proper item information in the view or edit form.

Currently the Url looks like this:

https://web.com/Lists/listname/EditFormCx.aspx?ID={$thisNode/@ID}

How do I modify this to still point to the {$thisnode/@ID} but ALSO include the 
"?Source=http://web.com/list/lisname/viewname.aspx"  ??